# calculating BOUNDS of google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

m working with google maps for the first time. and my app api needs bounds of google map as a paramater. i dont know how to calculate it?

I have searched a bit but couldnt able to get anything.

```
33.867269,151.200857,-33.862022,151.215449 //look like this..
```

Thanks..

Comment: Complete your question, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the bounds of current visible position of google map

```
VisibleRegion vr = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
        LatLng sw = vr.latLngBounds.southwest;
        LatLng ne = vr.latLngBounds.northeast;
        LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
```

the the four points will be your southwest latitude,longitude and northeast latitude, longitude .

```
 bounds.southwest.latitude , bounds.southwest.longitude ,bounds.northeast.latitude , bounds.northeast.longitude
```

Comment: Only true if the Camera bearing is 0.